# Kurento + Java Spring Client + IOS - Web to IOS communication

Tags: ios, webrtc, kurento

We are trying out Kurento 6.0 + Java Spring Client. The Examples works well (one2one call + one2one-recording). We are trying to implement the same functionality on an IOS app so that we can do Peer (IOS) -> Peer (Web) calls. But unfortunately - the documentation is not very clear.

The Kurento Server and Java Spring Boot application are deployed to an AWS ec2 instance and stun servers are configured.

We are using the call https://kurento-IP:8443/call with json to register:

```
var message = {
   id : 'register',
   name : name
};

ws.send(message)
```

And it works!

**Question:**

How can we now initiate a call in IOS after that?

Should the iOS be communicating to the Spring App (https://kurento-IP:8443/call) or directly to [ws://kurento-ip:8888/kurento](http://ws://kurento-ip:8888/kurento)  (We guess should be both?)

On the Web the JS does the following to make a call:

```
webRtcPeer = new kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv(options,
      function(error) {
         if (error) {
            return console.error(error);
         }
         this.generateOffer(onOfferCall);
      });

onOfferCall - calls directly the Web!
```

We were looking into the [Kurento IOS documentation](http://kurento-ios.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev_guide.html), but couldn't yet figure out. How can we convert this into IOS?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a way to initialize the one2one call + one2one-recording on the iOS client? I've also installed the Kurento server, but the iOS client SDK does not offer the feature for the one2one call + one2one-recording (it only has Room and Tree demo). Some help where to get started or some code would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: We ended up using the room and it worked fine!

Comment: How did you manage the recording part though?

Comment: Reading through the docs it seems that recording is not possible in a Room chat.

Comment: It's possible - there are people who have implemented. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/MK6u0UTTM9Y or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/jj5rwkcTJco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iOS app should be sending the messages to the signaling server. I'd suggest you read [this](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introducing_kurento.html) small introduction from the documentation, and spend some time understanding where your application architecture fits in this diagram
[image]

Hint: It's not the first one ;-)

Comment: Thanks @igracia. We'll have a look and get back to you. BTW - we got something partially working.

Comment: @avijendr Cool! Great to hear that. Also, please don't forget marking the answer if it's correct.